# If statement for D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm looking to create an if statement for an svg container to institute a next/back button UI. I am having troubles creating a statement that will if yes (1), perform a particular function.

For example,

```
if (d3.select("svg").attr("id") == "#chart") function updateData1() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you explain how are you using d3? if you're checking an id, you don't need d3 to select and check your ui, i.e. `document.querySelector('svg').id === 'chart'` maybe you're trying to do something else ? d3 has many other powerful methods, for example https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_call

Comment: function nextData() {
 
// if (d3.select("svg").attr("id") == "#chart") function updateData1() {
 
 chart.selectAll("*").remove();
 
 var map = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
  .attr("width", SVGwidth)
  .attr("height", SVGheight)...}

Comment: So im trying to create a logic gate, if a particular id is noted, it will then proceed to another code, below i mentioned about telling a story through scenes. So i will be able to identify what scene to proceed to through what id is found.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but generally I think what you are asking should look like:

```
if (d3.select("svg").attr("id") == "#chart")
{
    updateData1();
}
```

And have updateData1() defined somewhere else, possibly in the same file as:

```
function updateData1()
{
     ...
}
```

If you post more of your scenario it might be easier to help address your troubles.

Comment: Thanks for that, I am creating a D3 visualisation project, and am cycling through a series of 'scenes'. First slide been a background story, second been a graph, third something else. My problem is, i am currently using the buttons and they only activate once, so 'next', will lead to the next slide, but not to a subsequent slide. My idea was to use if statement and if the current slide had a particular id, it would move to the next. Thus dealing with the issue noted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could implement such logic.
In case your content is very different for each scene, you can remove the svg content. Keep in mind, you always can use the enter update exit pattern https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218 if you want to modify your svg content.

```js
const width = 200
const height = 200

const svg = d3.select('#app') // add main svg to #app
               .append('svg') 
               .attr('width', width)
               .attr('height', height)
               
let scene = 0 // keep track of scene counter
// button event 
d3.select('#nextBtn').on('click', function(){ 
  scene = nextEvent(svg, scene) //call event and update scene
})

function nextEvent(svg, scene){
  if(scene === 0){
    svg.select('*').remove()  // clean svg content
    svg.append('rect')
       .attr('width', 50)
       .attr('height', 50)
       .attr('x', 10)
       .attr('y', 10)
  }
  if(scene === 1){
    svg.select('*').remove() 
    svg.append('circle')
       .attr('r', 50)
       .attr('cx', 85)
       .attr('cy', 85)
  }
  if(scene === 2){
    svg.select('*').remove() 
    svg.append('rect')
       .attr('width', 90)
       .attr('height', 90)
       .attr('x', 50)
       .attr('y', 50)
  }
  return (scene + 1)%3 // return counter up to3 scenes 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<button id="nextBtn"> next </button>
<div id="app"></div>
```